# OneDrive API does not send the auth code to program

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, onedrive

I have this easy code sample for the OneDrive API on Python:

```
import onedrivesdk
from onedrivesdk.helpers import GetAuthCodeServer

redirect_uri = "https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf"
client_secret = "client-secret-code1234"

client = onedrivesdk.get_default_client(client_id='00000000123456F',
                                        scopes=['wl.signin',
                                                'wl.offline_access',
                                                'onedrive.readwrite'])

auth_url = client.auth_provider.get_auth_url(redirect_uri)

#this will block until we have the code
code = GetAuthCodeServer.get_auth_code(auth_url, redirect_uri)

client.auth_provider.authenticate(code, redirect_uri, client_secret)

returned_item = client.item(drive="me", id="root").children["newfile.txt"].upload("./newfile.txt")
```

So, when I run this my browser opens and I can choose Yes or No for the permissions of my App. When I choose Yes it should send the `auth code` back to my python program and upload the file in `returned_item`. 
But it does not come back.

Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Are you sure that redirect_uri is correct? Shouldn't it be something like "http://localhost:8080/"?

Comment: When I change it to `/localhost:8080/` it doesn't even open up the screen where I get asked...

Comment: add 'http://localhost' to your "redirect URLs" in your app settings in the [ Microsoft account Developer Center](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=193157)

Answer (score 0):

In the oauth authentication flow, after successful authentication of your app the authentication token needs to be sent somewhere. The `redirect_uri` is where the browser is heading after the authentication.

The case here is that a server listening on http://localhost:8080 is created by the call to `GetAuthCodeServer.get_auth_code(auth_url, redirect_uri)`, waiting for the token. 
So you need to use this url as `redirect_uri`.

Also in order to allow this redirect, you need to add it as 'trusted' in your [App Settings](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=193157) under 'API Settings'. 
And make sure 'Mobile or desktop client app' is set to 'yes'.